# Nested Observable in Angular 5

Tags: angular, nested, observable, angular5

This code below is my nested observable code. but I want to change my code more smart way. so I would like to change this code to not using nested way.

How can I change this code to non nested way??

```
user: User;
places: Place[];
user_id: string;

this.loginService.getLoginData(email, password).subscribe(
  res1 => {
    this.user = res1;
    this.storageService.saveUserInfo(this.user.userinfo);

    this.loginService
      .getPlaces(this.user.userinfo.token)
      .subscribe(
        res2 => {
          this.places = res2;
          const placeList = this.places.result.place_list.map(place => {
            return place.place_cd;
          });
          const userInfo = new UserInfoImpl(
            this.user.userinfo.email,
            this.user.userinfo.name,
            placeList
          );
          const account = new AccountImpl(
            this.user.userinfo.token,
            userInfo
          );
          this.loginService.postAccount(account).subscribe(
            res3 => {
              this.user_id = res3;
              if (this.user_id) {
                this.storageService.saveUserId(this.user_id);
              }
            },
            err => {
              console.log('err!!! ', err.message);
            }
          );
        },
        err => {
          console.log('err!!! ', err.message);
        }
      );
  },
  err => {
    console.log('err!!! ', err.message);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `.concatMap` operator. Although `.mergeMap` `.switchMap` would also work.

Simplified code:

```
this.loginService.getLoginData()
    .do((data) => this.storeTheData)
    .concatMap((logindata) => this.loginService.getPlaces())
    .concatMap((placesdata) => this.loginService.postAccount())
    .subscribe()
```

Since you really do a lot of side effects and your code is not completely reactive, there's also a different approach to this. You can listen to stored login data changes to load other data for you. I'm gonna lay out a simple version of that which may not make much sense standalone.

```
class Store {
    loginData = new ReplaySubject<LoginData>(1);
    placesData = new ReplaySubject<PlacesData>(1);
}

class AuthService {
    constructor(private store: Store, private http: Http) {

    }

    login() {
            this.http.post("login").subscribe(data => this.store.loginData.next(data));
    }
}

class PlacesService {
    constructor(store: Store, http: Http) {
        store.loginData
             .switchMap((loginData) => http.get("places" + loginData.placesId))
             .subscribe(places => store.places.next(places)
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont forget to unsubscribe too. Especially important in SPA such as Angular

Comment: thank you very mush sir ! I imagined I can use those 3 maps but I didn't know how to use those maps. I also thought Observable.folkJoin() but this is not for series case but for Parallel right ?  your advise is very helpful . thank you again sir! and sorry for my poor english!